# How to control a tableView content with a Slider?

Tags: qml, slider, tableview

I have a Table View and i want to scroll the information with a slider

How  can i get the length of the model and binding to the value of the Slider
i tried with
`onValueChanged: { console.log("Slider value:", control.value); console.log("Rounded value:", Math.round(control.value)); Model.currentRow  = Math.round(control.value); }`
but don't work

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "control a tableView content?" You could make each delegate fill the entire size of your Page and then just turn on the ScrollBars?

Answer (score 0):

If your data can be represented in a `ListModel`, you could consider rendering them in a `ListView` whereby each delegate fills the entire `ListView`. That way you can only see one delegate at a time. Then, the `ListView`'s own `ScrollBar` can be used to implement a slider to navigate between these delegates.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ListModel {
        id: pets
        ListElement { name: "cat"; color: "black" }
        ListElement { name: "dog"; color: "brown" }
        ListElement { name: "bird"; color: "white" }
    }
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: pets
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
            height: 40
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            stepSize: pets.count > 1 ? 1.0 / (pets.count-1) : 0
            snapMode: ScrollBar.SnapOnRelease
        }
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        delegate: Frame {
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: ListView.view.height - 40
            background: Rectangle { color: index & 1 ? "#aaa" : "#eee" }
            padding: 0
            ColumnLayout {
                anchors.fill: parent
                spacing: 0
                InfoText { text: "index: %1".arg(index) }
                InfoText { text: model.name }
                InfoText { text: model.color }
            }
        }
    }
}

// InfoText.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Label {
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    background: Frame { }
    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)